# How to compare every second column cell to a specific value?

Tags: excel, excel-2007, spreadsheet, worksheet-function

I have a problem in Excel 2007. I need to compare one value - letter "C" - to a range of cells that are on one row. The problem is that the values should be in every other cell.

So if I have a row  like this - C 434 C 324 C 3453 - it should say in a cell in the end - OK
And if I have a row like this - C 22 B 665 C 8877 - it should say - error as not all are C's.

Should be done as a formula not VBA.

So the question is is it possible to check if every other cell in a row ( a range ) contains a value C and output a value based on that.

PS! There are too many rows to do it by hand like this (pseudocode) 
=IF(AND(A1="C"; A3="C");"ok";"error")

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's something you can try. It requires the use of some extra cells, but it should get the job done. Let's say you start with this data:

```
Col_A  Col_B  Col_C  Col_D  Col_E  Col_F  Col_G  Col_H  Col_I
C 434  xxx    C 435  xxx    C 436  xxx    C 437  xxx    C 435
C 435  xxx    C 436  xxx    C 437  xxx    C 438  xxx    C 436
C 436  xxx    C 437  xxx    C 438  xxx    C 439  xxx    C 437
C 437  xxx    B 438  xxx    C 439  xxx    C 440  xxx    C 438
C 438  xxx    C 439  xxx    C 440  xxx    C 441  xxx    C 439
C 439  xxx    C 440  xxx    C 441  xxx    B 442  xxx    C 440
C 440  xxx    C 441  xxx    C 442  xxx    C 443  xxx    C 441
C 441  xxx    C 442  xxx    C 443  xxx    C 444  xxx    C 442
C 442  xxx    C 443  xxx    C 444  xxx    C 445  xxx    C 443
C 443  xxx    B 444  xxx    C 445  xxx    C 446  xxx    B 444
```

... let's say "Col_A" is in cell `A1`, and the actual data starts in cell `A2`. Select cell `A13` and enter the following formula:

```
=IF(OR(LEFT(A2)="C", MOD(COLUMN(A2),2)=0),1,0)
```

Now click `A13` and drag to the right to extend it to `I13`.
Drag that whole range down to `A22:I22`. You should have a field of ones and zeros in those cells now.

Next, click cell `K2` and enter the formula:

```
=IF(PRODUCT(A13:I13),"Valid","Not valid!")
```

Click cell `K2` and drag it down to extend it to `K11`.

That's it; you can hide the block of cells with all the ones and zeros if you want.

Disclaimer: only tested in OO Calc. Should work in Excel too though.

Comment: Thanks, needed to modify it a bit to make it do more what I wanted but it was a god-sent help :)

Answer (score 0):

**I could try something like this:**

> `=IF(OR(LEFT(A2,1)<>"C",LEFT(B2,1)<>"C",LEFT(C2,1)<>"C",LEFT(D2,1)<>"C",LEFT(E2,1)<>"C"),"Not Valid","Valid")`
>
> Col_A  Col_B   Col_C   Col_D   Col_E   VALIDATION
> C 434   C 435   C 436   C 437   C 435    Valid
> C 435   C 436   C 437   C 438   C 436    Valid
> C 436   C 437   C 438   C 439   C 437    Valid
> C 437   B 438   C 439   C 440   C 438    Not Valid
> C 438   C 439   C 440   C 441   C 439    Valid
> C 439   C 440   C 441   B 442   C 440    Not Valid
> C 440   C 441   C 442   C 443   C 441    Valid
> C 441   C 442   C 443   C 444   C 442    Valid
> C 442   C 443   C 444   C 445   C 443    Valid
> C 443   B 444   C 445   C 446   B 444    Not Valid

With this you don't need to add Columns, because validates every `string` in the same formula.